# Unable to access webserver on internal network either via domain or ip address

Tags: domain-name-system, firewall, vlan, fortigate

I am currently trying to set up a FortiGate 40F firewall. But somehow I am unable to get access to the server from the same network going via the external IP or domain.

I got a VLAN set as 10.0.4.x for the webserver. So the IP internally for the webserver is 10.0.4.2 and externally its IP is 85.25.160.200 and I have set an A-record to go to that IP for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). However when I am on the same network connected (10.0.4.x) with another machine or the server I am unable to connect to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) or 85.25.160.200. While it works flawlessly via a different network.

I got a Virtual IP coupled from 85.25.160.200(wan) to 10.0.4.2(VLAN). Policies for incoming and outgoing traffic set to HTTP/HTTPS and DNS.

I feel like I'm missing a setting somewhere in the Firewall.

How can I fix this issue?

Also, i'm actually a software engineer not a networking engineer.

Comment: It's probably hairpin NAT. Why do you need to get to the external ip address from the internal network?

Comment: You need [hairpin NAT](https://kb.fortinet.com/kb/documentLink.do?externalID=FD36202)

Comment: Thank you for the replies, I will try hairpin NAT tomorrow. And there is no real reason that  I need it, but it would be nice to just go to the domain to see if stuff is working without me switching around networks and remote desktops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to joequerty and vidaro, I have found the solution.
I indeed had to create an additional policy routing all traffic internally back to the VIP of the server. Works like a charm now.

Thanks guys!